# help im getting multiple apport messages while im installing ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apport

for those who are going to tell that i have to check if there's a io error on the USB drive, no, there's no io error on this plus i fully flashed the iso with no interruptions on balenaEtcher

Comment: "*[N]o interruptions on balenaEtcher*" is not proof of a fully successful creation of the bootable LiveUSB installer. Lots of folks have had "no interruptions" but an unusable final product.

Comment: We cannot see your screen. Please share with us the actual messages you're getting.